# How to build Apache POI - Java API To Access Microsoft Format Files from sources?

Tags: apache-poi

I need to build https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/4.1.2 project from sources. Since I didn't find any sources except these https://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/src/poi-src-4.1.2-20200217.zip I am trying to build them.

```
gradle build
...
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ooxml:ant-fetch-ooxml-xsds'.
> Can't get https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Office%20Open%20XML%201st%20edition%20Part%204%20(PDF).zip to /home/katya/tmp_work/poi-4.1.2/ooxml-lib/OfficeOpenXML-Part4.zip
```

Could you tell me where to get working sources of Apache POI version 4.1.2? I must build this library from sources version 4.1.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI's source code can be obtained from [the official SVN reposoitory](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/) or from [the mirror GIT repository on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/poi).

[Apache POI Developer Guide](https://poi.apache.org/devel) should give you enough information to get started. There's also a [general readme](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/README.rst) on GitHub.

The "Apache POI - How To Build" section from the Apache POI Developer Guide:

> ## Apache POI - How To Build
>
> ### JDK Version
>
> POI 4.0 and later require JDK version 1.8 or later.
>
> POI 3.11 and later 3.x versions require JDK version 1.6 or later.
>
> POI 3.5 to 3.10 required the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 required JDK 1.4+.
>
> ### Install Apache Ant
>
> The POI build system requires [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) version 1.8 - 1.9.x for Java 1.6 and higher. Newer versions (1.10.x) require Java 8 or higher.
>
> The current source code has been tested to work with Ant version 1.9.x and 1.10.x.
>
> Remember to set the ANT_HOME environment variable to where Ant was installed/extracted and add ANT_HOME/bin to your shell's PATH.
>
> If you are unsure about the correct value for ANT_HOME, search your file system for "ant.jar". This file will be in the directory %ANT_HOME%/lib." For example, if the path to ant.jar is "C:/Programs/Ant/lib/ant.jar", then set ANT_HOME to "C:/Progams/Ant".
>
> ### Install Apache Forrest
>
> The POI build system requires [Apache Forrest](https://forrest.apache.org/) to build the documentation.
>
> Specifically, the build has been tested to work with Forrest 0.90.
>
> Remember to set the FORREST_HOME environment variable.
>
> ### Building Targets with Ant
>
> The main targets of interest to our users are:
>
> | Ant Target | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | clean | Erase all build work products (ie. everything in the build directory). |
> | compile | Compiles all files from main, ooxml and scratchpad. |
> | test | Run all unit tests from main, ooxml and scratchpad. |
> | jar | Produce jar files. |
> | assemble | Produce .zip and tar.gz distribution packages. |
> | docs | Generate all documentation (Requires Apache Forrest). |
> | jenkins | Runs the tests which Jenkins, our Continuous Integration system, does. This includes the unit tests and various code quality checks. |
>
> ### Working with Eclipse
>
> Apache POI includes a pre-defined Eclipse project file which can be used to quickly get set up in the Eclipse IDE.
>
> First make sure that Java is set up properly and that you can execute the 'javac' executable in your shell.
>
> Next, open Eclipse and create either a local SVN repository, or a copy of the Git repository, and import the project into Eclipse.
>
> Right-click on "build.xml", and select "Run As / Ant Build...". The "Edit Configuration" dialog should appear. In the "Targets" tab, select the "Compile" target and click on "Run".
>
> Note: when executing junit tests from within Eclipse, you might need to set the system property "POI.testdata.path" to the actual location of the 'test-data' directory to make the test framework find the required test-files. A simple value of 'test-data' usually works.
>
> ### Working with IntelliJ Idea
>
> Import the Gradle project into your IDE. Execute a build to get all the dependencies and generated code in place.
>
> Note: when executing junit tests from within IntelliJ, you might need to set the system property "POI.testdata.path" to the actual location of the 'test-data' directory to make the test framework find the required test-files. A simple value of 'test-data' usually works.
>
> ### Using Maven
>
> Building Apache POI using Maven is not currently officially supported, and we strongly suggest continuing to use the official Ant build.
>
> However, including Apache POI within your own Maven project is fully supported, and widely used. Please see the [Components Page](https://poi.apache.org/components/) for details of the Maven artifacts available.
>
> ### Setting environment variables
>
> Linux: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)
>
> Windows: [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS.2C_OS.2F2_and_Windows)
>
> by Glen Stampoultzis, Tetsuya Kitahata, David Fisher
>
> -- https://poi.apache.org/devel/#Using+Maven

Comment: This sources "git clone --depth 1 --branch REL_4_1_2 https://github.com/apache/poi.git" has the same problem "Can't get https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Office%20Open%20XML%201st%20edition%20Part%204%20(PDF).zip"

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/ has the files

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net Did you follow the building instructions exactly?

Comment: In other words: what build instruction have you used?

Comment: @jannis I am sorry I didn't follow the instruction, I just made "./gradlew build"

Comment: Well it seems that this particular revision is just broken (it's old - maybe the document was removed). But it happens in some Sonar-related project, which doesn't seem that essential for the funtionality. I'd try to exclude this project from the build process.

Comment: @jannis Sorry, I do not understand. Could you explain in details what are you going to do?